# How to overwrite the NaN value?

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to replace the NaN Value for 'BTC' Symbol with the logic below, but can't make it to overwrite the NaN value in the Column 'A'.

```
df['A'].loc['BTC'] = 1 - df['A'].groupby(level=0).sum()
```

I have also tried .fillna() and few other things, but could not make it to work.

```
df['A'].loc['BTC'] = df['A'].loc['BTC'].fillna(1 - df['A'].groupby(level=0).sum())
```

I have the following dataframe:

```
                         A     
    Date     Symbol  

  1/1/2017    BTC       Nan   
              ETH       0.45     
              XRP       0.3     
  1/2/2017    BTC       Nan    
              ETH       0.55     
              XRP       0.2
```

Comment: Can you explain what is the logic?

Comment: Use your logic inside np.where

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `transform` with replace by filtering by [`get_level_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.get_level_values.html):

```
mask = df.index.get_level_values(1) == 'BTC'
df.loc[mask, 'A'] =  df.loc[mask, 'A'].fillna(1 - df.groupby(level=0)['A'].transform('sum'))
print (df)
                    A
Date     Symbol      
1/1/2017 BTC     0.25
         ETH     0.45
         XRP     0.30
1/2/2017 BTC     0.25
         ETH     0.55
         XRP     0.20
```

**Detail**:

```
print (df.groupby(level=0)['A'].transform('sum'))
Date      Symbol
1/1/2017  BTC       0.75
          ETH       0.75
          XRP       0.75
1/2/2017  BTC       0.75
          ETH       0.75
          XRP       0.75
Name: A, dtype: float64
```

Comment: user needs `1 - sum()` i believe. so `(1/1/2017, BTC)` should be 0.25 for example

Comment: @jezrael, thank you so much for your solution. It worked perfectly for me.